# Rails 6.0.0 TypeError - no implicit conversion of nil into String:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication

people so I have this problem when trying to do a post API call. 
the situation is this: 
I have a large application where students sign up so I can manage them and contact them through that student management app.
Now I have created a smaller app where students can do their assignments, lets call that homework app;
I am doing a post API call to the bigger app in the login section so students don't have to sign up again and they can use the same information in both applications.
I am getting an internal server error 500; in the terminal the error is:

```
TypeError - no implicit conversion of nil into String:
 app/controllers/api/sessions_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

this is the create action in sessions controller in the student management app:

```
  def create
    unless request.format == :json
      sign_out
      render status: 406, json: { message: "JSON requests only." } and return
    end
    resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

    if resource.blank?
      render status: 401, json: { response: "Access denied." } and return
    end

    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location:
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource) do |format|
      format.json { render json:
        {
          success: true, jwt: current_token, response: "Authentication successful"
        }
      }
    end

  end
```

and most importantly the api call with a very simple html form:
ps: I am running the projects locally, thats why the url's are defined as localhost

```
<form class="login-form">
  <input type="email" class="mail mail-input" placeholder=" Email"><br>
  <input type="password" class="password pw-input" placeholder=" Password"><br>
  <button class="login" type="button" name="button">Login</button>
</form>

<script>

var login = document.querySelector(".login")
login.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var email = document.querySelector(".mail")
  var password = document.querySelector(".password")
  let loginValues = {
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value
  }
  $.post (
   "http://localhost:4000/api/login.json",
    {
      api_user: {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
      }
    },
    function (response){
      console.log(response)
      console.log('in');
      window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/")
    }
  )
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing this:

```
api_user: {
  email: email.value,
  password: password.value
}
```

With this:

```
user: {
  email: email.value,
  password: password.value
}
```

Tell me if it works?

***Update, based on comments:***

I really have no idea what you are doing in the code above, the code is really messy... Try replacing this:

```
respond_with resource, location:
after_sign_in_path_for(resource) do |format|
  format.json { render json:
    {
      success: true, jwt: current_token, response: "Authentication successful"
    }
  }
end
```

with this:

```
respond_with resource do |format|
  format.json { render json:
    {
      success: true, jwt: current_token, response: "Authentication successful"
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: it kinda worked. this is what shows in the console but it didn't actually logged me in nor redirect me to where i wanted it. 

Processing by Api::SessionsController#new as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.json
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.json (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Are you sure you have a user with those credentials? How are you handling a failed authentication?

Comment: 100% percent sure.
I have a method for invalid tokens and also in the controller i posted above there are some other failed auth actions.


  def invalid_auth_token
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sign_in_path, error: 'Login invalid or expired' }
      format.json { head 401 }
    end
  end

Comment: the error appears to be in this line when in the api call is api_user: resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options); 
but when i changed it to user there is no error but there is no redirect neither

Comment: I updated the answer, I am not sure how your code even works, try the changes I added and see if you are getting anything new.

Comment: you are right is messy, some else was working on it and i can tell there is a lot of copy paste so even me is struggling a bit to figure it out, getting the same error, no conversion of nil into string,  the error seems to be in the auth_options